# Are double consonants pronounced distinctively from single consonants in Esperanto?

Tags: pronunciation

For example: Is it best practice to pronounce Finnlando as [fin.nlando] (like double consonants in Arabic languages) or maybe [fin:lando] (like long consonants in old Scandinavian languages) or would Finlando & Finnlando be pronounced indistinguishably?

PS: Consider Rule#9 of the 16 Rules of Esperanto Grammar: "All words are read as they are written."

Comment: I think _Finnlando_ and _Finlando_ should be pronounced differently, as per the very rule you cited. [The Wiktionary pronunciation of _Finnlando_](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:Eo-Finnlando.ogg) corroborates this statement as it treats the double _n_ as an intensified sound. The sole exception to this rule would be non-Esperantized proper nouns, which merit deeper consideration.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is right in your question. "All words are read as they are written." So yes, double consonants are supposed to be pronounced like two consonants. Sometimes this is not easy - which is why *Suomio* is a popular alternative to *Finnlando.*

Comment: Thanks, for expanding my vocabulary.  I think I prefer Suomio to Finnlando.

Answer (score 5):

As you cite, the norm prescribes

> All words are read as they are written; there are no silent letters.

From this you can conclude not only that double consonants must be pronounced, but also pronounced as two sounds instead as one long consonant. So e.g. *ekkoleri* should be [ɛkkɔ'lɛri] with [kk] as in Polish *lekki* (light), not with [k:] as in Italian *vecchio* (old).

While this is clear for plosives like *p t k*, for non-plosives like *l m s* the distinction between double vs. long articulation is less perceivable (I am not aware of a language distinguishing between long and double sonorants), and so an easy pronounciation like [fin:'landɔ] is certainly tolerable.